In SSIS, when using Flat File Connection manager have columns be fixed width but delimited on rows by CRLF
I have a flat file where I want the columns to be delimited based on being fixed width, but I also need to delimit so that each row is defined by CRLF rather than a fixed Row width.
The file looks something like this:
John Doe   999.99   99.99|
Jane Jill  999.99   9.99|
Max Cumbers123.45   45.56|

Where the pipe | represents a line break.  So the row width may vary from row to row, BUT each column is defined by the width of the column rather than a delimiter.
